# When tried to access keyword from Custom Library, error InvalidArgumentException is displayed

Tags: robotframework

When tried to access keyword from Custom Library, error InvalidArgumentException is displayed

I am using below folder structure to maintain my test scripts

```
Test_Scripts

    TestCase
        TestSuite1.robot

    SupportFiles
        RF_CustomLibrary.py
```

TestSuite1.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library                             SeleniumLibrary
Library                            ..\\SupportFiles\\RF_CustomLibrary.py

*** Variables ***
${Browser}     Chrome

*** Test cases ***

Sample Test Case
    Verify Paste text functionality

*** Keywords ***
Verify Paste text functionality
    Set Library Search Order    RF_CustomLibrary
    Open Browser    https://gmail.com    ${BROWSER}
    Sleep    2s
    Maximize Browser Window
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    60s     2s   Element Should Be Visible       ${L_Login_btn}
    PasteTextFunction    id=identifierId    Username1
```

Custom library: RF_CustomLibrary.py

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from SeleniumLibrary import SeleniumLibrary
from SeleniumLibrary.base import LibraryComponent, keyword
from SeleniumLibrary.errors import ElementNotFound
from SeleniumLibrary.utils import is_noney


class RF_CustomLibrary(SeleniumLibrary):

    @keyword
    def pasteTextFunction(self, locator, text):
        os.system("echo off | clip")
        os.system("echo %s| clip" % text.strip())
        element = self._current_browser().find_element(locator)
        element.clear()
        element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
```

When i execute this test case, below error message is displayed for the keyword "***PasteTextFunction***"

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator
```

Any suggestions/inputs to sort out this error would be helpful.

Comment: When I run the above code I don't get that error. Instead I get `Multiple keywords with name 'Open Browser' found`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I missed this line in Custom keyword."Set Library Search Order    RF_CustomLibrary".  I have updated it in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the low-level selenium function `find_element`, but passing in a SeleniumLibrary-style locator (`id=identifierId`) which is not something that the low level selenium driver understands.

If you want to use a SeleniumLibrary locator, you need to use the  [Get webelement](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20WebElement) method of SeleniumLibrary instead.

```
element = self.get_webelement(locator)
```